# CSS background cover animation timing

Tags: html, css, animation, twitter-bootstrap-3, slide

I'm trying to get animation timing but it is not working. I have HTML code using bootstrap below and CSS code in relation.

What I want to do is set the background image to do the transition animation for a duration of 1.5s and the text that goes over it for a duration of 2.5s. But I realized that editing the css for "introB" would effect the whole jumbotron section, making the timing for both exactly the same.

I was wondering if anyone would know how to separate the background image with the text so that I can do two different animations for them.

HTML code

```
<section class="jumbotron" id="introB">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="introduction" class="slideUp">
            <h2 class="col-sm-9">I'm a Developer, Designer and Amateur Photographer living in Canada Ottawa.</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS code

```
#introB{
    background-image: url(../images/home.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    height: 800px;
    position: relative;

   animation-name: slideUp;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideUp;
    -ms-animation-name: slideUp;    
    -o-animation-name: slideUp; 

    animation-duration: 1.5s;   
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -ms-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -o-animation-duration: 1.5s;

    animation-timing-function: ease;    
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease;

    visibility: visible !important;
}

#introduction h2{
    font-size: 70px;
    color: white;
}

.slideUp{
    animation-name: slideUp;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideUp;
    -ms-animation-name: slideUp;    
    -o-animation-name: slideUp; 

    animation-duration: 2.5s;   
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2.5s;
    -ms-animation-duration: 2.5s;
    -o-animation-duration: 2.5s;

    animation-timing-function: ease;    
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease;

    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: My guess would be to separate the 2 containers if they gonna have different animations. Maybe you can wrap the h2 with another div and kill transition on that wrapper and add a new transition on the h2,

Comment: I fixed the problem! I tried your way but it still wasn't working. I took out the col-sm-9 for the h2 and it worked! I think trick was that each element can only have 1 class and the col-sm-9 was overpower the slideUp class.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Np, Good you got it working ;)